# Understanding mergeMap in redux Epic

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rxjs

I was wondering if someone could help me understand this piece of code (from the official redux docs)

```
const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action =>
    ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
      map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
    )
  )
);
```

I am aware what Epics are (actions in, actions out etc) and understand that the actions will go through via `action$.pipe` and then you pick the one you want through `ofType` and they must return another action.
However, I am having trouble understanding what happens after calling mergeMap.
From what I understand (which maybe very wrong), mergeMap will flatten and merge the outer observable (in this case `action$`) with the inner observable (in this case the call to get the json). From the inner observable, we are piping map, which will take the data from the api call and use it to call the next action.
I feel I am missing something here and not understand the observable flow. I did read through the official docs but I am having trouble fully grasping it.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap

Comment: Yes I read through that however it is not clear to me how it works in the context of the epic above.

Comment: You really need to understand rxjs first.

Comment: https://rxmarbles.com/ is a great resource the visualise the rx functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`actions$` is a stream of all the actions, `ofType(FETCH_USER)` filters the stream so that only FETCH_USER actions get through.
mergeMap takes the FETCH_USER action that is emitted by the stream and returns an observable that will emit once the http request is complete. The map function on the http request maps the response from the http request to another action.

Comment: Thanks, this was a very good explanation, helper me a lot

Answer (score -1):

`map` and `flatten` into single `Observable`
[image]